# BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81: Method with does not exist. Laravel ORM

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I'm new to laravel, currently using ORM I am trying to retrieve data from parentCategory table by using foreign key present in category table.

following is the code in my category model:

```
  <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class category extends Model
{
    protected $table='category';

    public function parentCategory(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\parentCategory','mCategoryId');

    }

}
```

following is my parentCategory model code:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class parentCategory extends Model
{
    protected $table='maincategory';



   public function categories(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\category');

    }

}
```

following is the code of my categoryController by which i am using to retrieve data:

```
class categoryController extends Controller
{
    function index(){

        $category=category::all()->with('parentCategory');
        $parentCategory=parentCategory::all();
        return view('admin.category',['categories'=>$category,'parentCategories'=>$parentCategory]); 

    }

    function add(Request $request){

        $category= new category();
        $category->categoryName=$request["name"];
        $category->mCategoryId=$request["parentCategory"];      
        $category->save();
        return redirect()->route('category');

    }
}
```

**the error further states:**
*at Collection->__call('with', array('parentCategory')) in categoryController.php line 17*

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In your `index()` function, you can try

```
$category = category::with('parentCategory')->get();
```

This should solve the problem. Follow the [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) documentation.